# 1980's book about a boy on a space station that goes to a forbidden Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in the mid to late 80's. All I remember is that there are humans living on a space station (or possibly on the Moon) above an Earth that was devastated by some disaster. It is forbidden for anyone to go to Earth. A young boy steals a shuttle and goes to Earth and meets a young girl for some adventures. I recall that there was a pet involved, but I don't remember if it came with the boy from the space station or if it belonged to the girl.

I recall the book as being rather light fare and not hard sci-fi or heavy drama. I likely read it around 1986 when I was 13 or 14.

Comment: There are a few similarities to the _Bohemian Rhapsody_ episode of the animé series _Cowboy Bebop_.  (Although you really have to distort the imagination a bit to make it all fit in :))

Comment: I read something similar in the 1960's, the boy lived on one of several space stations, I seem to remember his was station 'K'

Answer (score 3):

The beginning of your question sounds remarkably like [Exile to Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exile_to_Hell) by Asimov from 1968, but that was only a short story. Maybe your book was based on it?